# How to simplify this battleship program? (Python)

Tags: python, list, if-statement, random

Bear with me, I'm new to programming and I know for a fact this contains a lot of unnecessary code.

Is there a way to add more ships without the code extending forever?
Also a better way to code the comparisons under my while loop. Thanks for taking the time to read and comment.

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(10):
    board.append(["O"] * 10)

# creating the "map" of "O"'s for an ocean - 10x10
def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

# random number for row from 0 to length of board (9) in this case
def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

# random number for column from 0 to length of board (9) in this case
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

# 1st ship, size = 1x1
ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

# 2nd ship, size = 1x2
ship_row2 = random_row(board)
if ship_row2 == ship_row: #Did not want a ship coordinate to fall onto a previous ship
    ship_row2 = random_row(board) #so I set it to generate a new number if it did
ship_row2_1 = ship_row2 - 1 #2nd part of this ship, needs to be adjacent so I set - 1 (could be +1)
if not ship_row2_1 >= 0: # if first part is 0, then ship_row2_1 would be off the "map",
    ship_row2_1 += 2 #so I added 2 to bring it to a positive number


ship_col2 = random_col(board)#same things as above for the column code
if ship_col2 == ship_col:
    ship_col2 = random_col(board)
ship_col2_1 = ship_col2


turn = 0
ships_sunk = 0
while True:
    try:
        guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
        guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))
        # so my code here basically says if you hit the 1x1 ship it should turn it to an X,
        #and not be able to hit it again.
        if (guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col) and (board[guess_row][guess_col] != "X"):
            print "\nCongratulations! You sunk a battleship!"
            print "One more to go!\n"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            print_board(board)
            ships_sunk += 1
            if ships_sunk == 2:
                print "\n You got them all! Pokemon!"
                break
        # here is the same but for the 1x2 ship, I had to turn them all to X to prevent user,
        # from hitting the same part of the "ship".
        elif ((guess_row == ship_row2 and guess_col == ship_col2) or \
        (guess_row == ship_row2_1 and guess_col == ship_col2_1)) and (board[guess_row][guess_col] != "X"):
            print "\nCongratulations! You sunk a battleship!"
            print "One more to go!\n"
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
            board[ship_row2][ship_col2] = "X"
            board[ship_row2_1][ship_col2_1] = "X"
            print_board(board)
            ships_sunk += 1
            if ships_sunk == 2:
                print "\n You got them all! Pokemon!"
                break
        else:
            if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > (len(board) -1 )) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > (len(board[0]) - 1)):
                print "\nOops, that's not even in the ocean."
            elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
                print "\nYou guessed that one already."
            elif type(guess_row) is not int or type(guess_col) is not int:
                print "Type a number!"
            else:
                print "\nYou missed my battleship!"
                board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
                turn += 1
                print_board(board)
                if turn == 4:
                    print "Game Over"
                    break
    except ValueError:
        print "Please type a number!"
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really match your title right now. If you want the question in the title answered, you might have better luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (although it may be too broad?). Otherwise, you might break this into one or two questions for here, e.g., "How can I add more ships easily?" with only a relevant portion of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the "game state" in a more flexible way. The same thing goes for the logic that determines when a player has won. One way of doing this would be to break down your application into [classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html), maybe something like:

- Battle class: contains ships for each side, scoring methods, dimensions for the battle area
- Ship class: size of the ship, amount of damage ship has sustained, ship's location

Whenever making a new Battle class, you could pass it an initial list of Ships for each side. These lists could be as long as you want (provided the ships can fit into the battle area without overlapping).